# How can I click this using selenium webdriver?

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I have an element like this:

`<a class="btn">Select</a>`

How do I click this using selenium webdriver?

Comment: How did you try?

Comment: Do NOT add unrelated tags to your questions! This is considered SPAM and could land you in jail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To `click()` on the link with text as **Select** you can use either of the following options :

- Python `link_text` :

  ```
  driver.find_element_by_link_text("Select").click()
  ```
- Python `xpath` :

  ```
  driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@class='btn' and contains(.,'Select')]").click()
  ```
- Java `linkText` :

  ```
  driver.findElement(By.linkText("Select")).click();
  ```
- Java `xpath` :

  ```
  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@class='btn' and contains(.,'Select')]")).click();
  ```